# How to get a loop to begin again from the beginning?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I am currently writing a program in C++ and I want to ask if I can make a loop to start the process again.
I use a while loop with a condition for when the program ends. The loop basically creates and writes the data from the object into a file. The user should be able to choose to whether make another file or exit the program and with each run the program should make a new file.

My problem is that the loop doesn't work with my exit condition and if I try to make another CD, it does not display any text indicating to the user that he can make another file. I want to make the program to restart by pressing space or any other character, but all that happens is (as I mentioned) no line gets printed and the program needs a text input different than q. I can't think of a good enough solution.

I tried to experiment with cin.ignore() and cin.peek() as I looked for answers but I still have the same problem and I can't find a better way to check whether the user wants to exit the program or to go on making files. Here is my code so far.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Cds {  // Class CDS
   public:
    Cds(){};          // constructor
    ~Cds(){};         // destructor
    void createCd();  // initialization for the function
    void Display();   // same here
   private:
    string mCdName;    // name of the cd
    string mCdSinger;  // name of the singer in the cd
    int mId;           // id number for the cd
};

void Cds::createCd() {
    /*
    Simple function for the user
    to give input for the name of the
    CD, the name of the artist
    and an id for the CD.
    */

    cout << "Input for name of cd: " << endl;
    cin >> mCdName;
    cout << endl << "Input for name of artist: " << endl;
    cin >> mCdSinger;
    cout << endl << "Input for CD Id: " << endl;
    cin >> mId;
}

void Cds::Display() {  // was used to debug the createCd function
    cout << endl << mCdName << endl;
    cout << endl << mCdSinger << endl;
    cout << endl << mId << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 0;  // initialization of the x check for when the program will end

    while (x == 0) {  // while loop

        Cds cd;         // creation of the object
        cd.createCd();  // call of the function createCd to give data to the
                        // objects
        ofstream CD("CD.txt");  // creation of a file to write the data
        CD.write((char*)&cd,
                 sizeof(cd));  // actually writing the data from the cd
        cout << "If you want to exit, press Q. " << endl;
        string w;  // string w to check if the user wants to exit
        cin >> w;  // user input for w
        if (w == "q" || w == "Q") {  // if the user presses q the program exits
            CD.close();
            x == 1;
            exit(0);
        } else {  // else it should restart but it doesn't
            cin.peek();
            x == 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CD.write((char*)&cd, sizeof(cd));` is completely wrong and can't possibly work with a class containing a `std::string`. This technique works only with `POD` types.

Comment: `x == 0;` is a pointless comparison (which you throw away the result of the comparison) not an assignment. `=` is an assignment. For example `x=0;` The `==` means compare the values for example `if (x == 0) {std::cout << "The variable x is zero.\n"};`

Comment: [introduction to loops and while statements](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-loops-and-while-statements/)

Comment: Another problem is reopening the same file in the loop overwriting the previous data you entered however with that said the data written was garbage / unusable because of my first comment. And finally a binary file probably should not have a `.txt` extension since its not text. I am not trying to be rude however you appear to be several weeks away from being able to realistically accomplish this programming task. My advice is to start with simpler projects and work your way up to this level of complexity.